# Update a PyPI package

Tags: python, pypi

Is there a way to update a PyPI package without changing the version number?

Imagine, for a second, that I've found a small bug in a package I recently uploaded to PyPI. Is there a way to edit/re-upload the code without incrementing the version number?

**UPDATE**
I guess I should clarify that by "bug" I mean the version number in the actual source code is wrong - it's not a functional thing, it just means if you do `package.version` you get the previous version, not the current one (and yes I know this *could* cause a bug in someone else's code, but given we're in alpha I'd hope version dependencies haven't set in just yet...). For the record, *clearly* silent bug fixes are bad!

**UPDATE 2**
As of Jan 2015 the solution provided is no longer valid - see [this post for more information.](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.distutils.devel/22739)

Comment: There's also [testPyPI](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi) if you want to load your package, run `pip3 install -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi <package name>`, and confirm the package passes unit tests before pushing to real PyPI. It works the same as PyPI -- so you also can't repeat uploads of the same version number there.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When you encountered a bug, *always* upload a *new* release.

Increase the version number, include a changelog, call it a brown-bag release (it wasn't me, it was someone wearing a brown bag over their heads, really, honestly).

You never know whom already may have downloaded a copy of the release (on a mirror, directly from your github page, whatever) that will *never know* that you fixed a bug quietly. Moreover, those that did figure out you replaced the release, now have to learn how to force a reinstall.

*Don't replace a released package with a silent bugfix. Do not be tempted. Just make a new release.*

If, on the other hand, you managed somehow to corrupt the distribution file itself, so the `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file is b0rken, then you need to manually remove the file using the PyPI web interface and re-upload.

As of the [24th of January](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2015-January/025683.html), PyPI will not even let you reuse a filename anymore; that means that you cannot re-upload a new file with the same version number.

If all you did wrong was a packaging error, you can add a `.postN` postfix to the version number (so `.post1`, `.post2`, etc.) to indicate a post-release update.