# A guide for updating packages on PyPi

Tags: pypi

I used [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to install a new package on PyPi.

Now, I want to update the package. 
Since I found no guide for this, I tried to do it myself: I updated the version from "1.0.0.dev1" to "1.0.0.dev2" and re-installed. It did not work: I got:

```
Uploading tee_table-1.0.0.dev1-py3-none-any.whl

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: File already exists. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13919830/827927) but the information seems outdated (from 2012).

Is there a simple user guide that describes how to  upload a new version of a package to PyPi?

Comment: The answer you mentioned is not outdated. Increase version number, recreate sdist/eggs/wheels and upload.

Comment: This is what I did... I got the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: I see **dev1** in the error message. You didn't increase it to **dev2** or didn't regenerate wheels.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I found out what my problem was - I did not delete the old files in the dist folder, so the uploader tried to upload them before the new files, and failed. The solution was to:

1. Delete all files in the `dist` folder.
2. Update the version number in the `setup.py` file.
3. Re-create the wheels:

   ```
   python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
   ```
4. Re-upload the new files:

   ```
   twine upload dist/*
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Sorry if i am replying too late but came across the same problem and found a way not to delete the existing dist folder:

after updating the version in setup.py and recreating the wheel file,

```
twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
```

will skip the distribution that already exist and upload the newer ones

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows** (I am on Windows 10), @Erel Segal-Halevi's answers doesn't work. Following worked for me.

c. Re-create the wheels:

```
py setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

d. Re-upload the new files:

```
py -m twine upload dist/*
```

Comment: When I run the first command, I get: `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'`. Do you know how to overcome this?

Comment: @Emil Have you wheel installed? ```pip install wheel```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you changed the version in the setup:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QstOY.png)

and then use the command:

```bash
twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, see [Trouble following packaging libraries tutorial: upload #313](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/313).
I was confused about whether to use `twine upload --repository testpypi dist*` to update a package or `twine upload --repository-url URL dist/*` to update an existing package. The documentation on the issue is not clear to me. Also, I have encountered all sorts of issues while using API tokens for authentication. What worked for me was the following suggestion:

> The correct URLs for the repositories are
> `https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/` and `https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`.

So, if you wish to update an existing package using an **API token**:

- change the version of the project in `pyproject.toml` from, e.g., `0.0.1` to `0.0.2`
- `-m build`
- `-m twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`
- generate a project-scoped API token on PyPi and use it for authentication