# How to update pip package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a package hosted on pip (`pip install coolours`). If I change the code or readme for the package how do I update it? I have tried to re-upload it with twine but I get an error stating that the package already exists.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Not really an answer, but a circumvention. You can use a package manager like [poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/) to properly handle details like that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's on PyPi, use this: [A guide for updating packages on PyPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700692/a-guide-for-updating-packages-on-pypi).

> I found out what my problem was - I did not delete the old files in
>   the dist folder, so the uploader tried to upload them before the new
>   files, and failed. The solution was to:
>
> a. Delete all files in the dist folder.
>
> b. Update the version number in the setup.py file.
>
> c. Re-create the wheels:
>
> ```
> python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
> ```
>
> d. Re-upload the new files:
>
> `twine upload dist/*`