# An updated guide on releasing and versioning PyPi packages

Tags: python, pypi, pyproject.toml

I have recently bumped into an issue while trying to release a new version of my PyPi package.

After updating the source code (and preparing the files for the release), I cannot find any updated guide on how to release a new version (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700692/a-guide-for-updating-packages-on-pypi), for instance) to PyPi.

Most guides reference `setup.py`, which has now been replaced by `pyproject.toml`.

So, from Windows (IDE: VScode), the old command

```
py setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

does not work anymore. When replacing `setup.py` with `pyproject.toml`
I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\generic\pyproject.toml", line 3
    build-backend = "hatchling.build"
   ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator
```

My `pyproject.toml` is built like any generic `pyproject.toml` file

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE"
version = "0.0.2"
authors = [
  { name="Example Author", email="author@example.com" },
]
description = "A small example package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues"
```

I am aware of the [Python Packages guide](https://py-pkgs.org/07-releasing-versioning.html). However, they explain how to release using `git`, and I'd like an equivalent for the old method.

As user @phd pointed out, there are some [guides](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) out there. However, these only mention how to upload a new package to PyPi, not a new distribution release. Also, they do not address uploads with API tokens. Am I supposed to create a new API token? Old tokens are not accessible anymore but new ones return the following error:

```
ERROR    HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
         Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://test.pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.
```

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/ , https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html

Comment: @phd I am still confused. Both tutorials indicate how to build the first distribution, but not how to update an existing package/update the new release.

Comment: Python packaging don't distinguish "first distribution" from any other. Change version, build package(s), `twine upload`, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

For reference, see [Trouble following packaging libraries tutorial: upload #313](https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/313).
I was also confused about whether to use `twine upload --repository testpypi dist*` to update a package or `twine upload --repository-url URL dist/*` to update an existing package. The documentation on the issue is not clear to me. Also, I have encountered all sorts of issues while using API tokens for authentication. What worked for me was the following suggestion:

> The correct URLs for the repositories are
> `https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/` and `https://test.pypi.org/legacy/`.

So, if you wish to update an existing package using an **API token**:

- change the version of the project in `pyproject.toml` from, e.g., `0.0.1` to `0.0.2`
- `-m build`
- `-m twine upload --repository-url https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*`
- generate a project-scoped API token on PyPi and use it for authentication