# How to update Python Package on PyPi?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I created a package in Python named wiki-scraper but while installing from PyPi I am getting the following error.

```
Collecting wiki-scraper
  Using cached wiki_scraper-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\rigve\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wiki-scraper) (0.0.1)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement re (from wiki-scraper)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for re
```

The contents of the equirements.txt is:

```
re 
nltk
bs4
requests
```

I rectified the error by removing `re` from requirements.txt but I don't know how to update my package on PyPI. I have seen many methods but they are way too long also I don't know how to delete the existing version on PyPI. How can I update my package on PyPI?

Comment: What difficulty are you facing updating your python package on pypi?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-the-distribution-archives

Answer (score 0):

The error is simply stating that `pip` cannot find a package `re`, which was required.

The reason is simple: [there is no package named 're' on PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=re)

[`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is a standard Python module. So there is no reason to install it using `pip`, and attempting to do so will result in this error.

NB: I don't have experience with creating packages on PyPI, but I expect that you should simply create a new version (with a different version number) and upload that. It probably isn't possible to update your current version. See [Update a PyPI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919830/update-a-pypi-package) for more info about that.